# EF database categories need suggestions

Tags: entity-framework, categories

all and thanks for your help as i got a lot from you.

Now I have problems with understanding C#, MVC4  (EF: code first) and especial creating model for making 
non linear model: the task is to make categories/subcategories from external source, where i don't know the structure off categories and subcategories and what sub's level is. Its like category tree and at the end lets say its products.
Right now I made paper work, and don't know how to code this.:

In my opinion there should be enough two model classes:
1.) Category
2.) Product

```
1. like this.



public class categories
 {
   double sub { get; set; }
   tring name { get; set; }
   link { get; set; }
   int colum { get; set; }
 }
```

2.

```
public class products {    
string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
        double where_iam_from { get; set; }
        string ManufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }
        string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In categories as i think there should be 2 numbers in field sub.. lets say for firs category from 10-99, if there is subcategory it becomes 1010, or 1110, and so till subcategories end. managed by code, and i will know full tree from this number in products. And product need to have this end value: where_iam_from, category tree, to find all way back.

And I don't know how to associate model classes; a big newbie.

I'm not sure if if i write understandable, if need more details i will sure add them.

Thank you all.

Edit: to make a bit clear: 
 What i think i need in database is lines off products, and categories. And I want to use same class for categories, and sub-categories, and one for products. All the reference should be only
'where_iam_from', eg number. By this number doing math i should get full category list. example:

```
Category1 := 10;
  Category1_sub1:=1010;
  Category1_sub2:=1011;
    Category1_sub2_sub1:=101110;
Category2:= 11;
  Category2_sub1:=1110;
```

and so on for categories. And for products only reference to last sub number in categories lets say 101112101530; so by number length i can get sub level and with divide get full categories.
Can i do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understood the question correctly. But if you want to divide products into categories you could use something like this for EF code first.

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        this.ChildCategories = new HashSet<Category>();
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

// The database (DbContext) class

public class MyDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{

    public Application()
    {
        MyDb db = new MyDb();
        Category categoryOne = new Category { CategoryName = "Category One" };¨
        Product productOne = new Product { ProductName = "Product One" };
        productOne.Category = categoryOne;
        db.Products.Add(productOne);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var productInCategory = db.Category.Where(x => x.CategoryName == "Category One").Include("Products").Products.ToList();

    }

}
```

I hope it can move you forward in your project.
A good start is to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Hi, thanks for support. I don't fully understand the code, will look ahead in it. Maybe you can add some comments and how it use in code. And how database should look by code. Thanks again.